asp:listview web control set column width
I have an asp:ListView web control on a web form and want to set the column width.
I don't mind if this is done at design time or in code at run time. The problem is that asp:ListView doesn't seem to have a Columns property, either at design or run time. There are references to a columns property in discussions on the web but I think they may be referring to a different ListView, maybe for a mobile app or WPF or Windows. Mine is the webforms asp:ListView. I have tried hooking the OnInit and OnLayoutCreated events which are called as: protected void ListView1_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e) but the sender parameter doesn't seem to provide a means of sizing the columns. Many thanks for help with this.
